# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is the cut-off frequency of a moving average filter?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9966/what-is-the-cut-off-frequency-of-a-moving-average-filter)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Speech segmentation for speaker recognition](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9980/speech-segmentation-for-speaker-recognition)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Two generated tones creates a side tone - how to avoid the side tone](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10096/two-generated-tones-creates-a-side-tone-how-to-avoid-the-side-tone)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Spectral Entropy Calculation in MATLAB](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10137/spectral-entropy-calculation-in-matlab)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [DFT and multiplication/convolution equivalence](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10146/dft-and-multiplication-convolution-equivalence)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Estimation of Glottal Closure Instant](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10193/estimation-of-glottal-closure-instant)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Isolating Bat Species without prior training base](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10229/isolating-bat-species-without-prior-training-base)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Missing harmonics (power-line)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10237/missing-harmonics-power-line)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Spectral Shape and properties](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/spectral-shape-and-properties)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Automated accent detection](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10174/automated-accent-detection)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)