# What is the criteria of a site being launched

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

I just came across the Area 51, and found that we have got [3 Okay and 2 Excellent evaluations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1691/signal-processing). Looks like our site probably needs some improvement on answer ratio and rate (I guess these two dropped from Excellent to Okay since the site looks much less active than it was two years ago). But there are also many launched sites that fail to obtain all-Excellent evaluations. So I was wondering whether there is a standard to determine whether a public beta site is launched or closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As background, please read [Does this site have a chance of succeeding?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

The two key bits of criteria are:

1. Does the site have a growing library of answered questions that attract new visitors?
2. Does the site have a growing community of experts to ask, answer, edit, evaluate, and organize new questions?

The Area 51 numbers help us answer those questions, but they are not the only indications we use.  For instance, we look at the results of the [site self-evaluation](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1253/4986). Digital Signal Processing has not quite reached the self-sustaining critical mass that we look for in a graduated site.  But it *does* seem to be making progress each time I look at it.